# REST: How to return content in the response body using PUT

Tags: rest

I am implementing a PUT this way

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = ServicesDictionary.API_DOMAIN_DEMAND + "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK, reason = "Update successful")
@ResponseBody
@Override
@LogMe("MarketDemandService.PUT.update")
public jsonObject update(@RequestBody @Valid MongoMarketDemand marketDemand, @PathVariable String id) {
    //do update
    return jsonObject
}
```

But when I see the ResponseEntity I see body is null. How can I return a json object?

Comment: I am also staring at a similar problem. @ResponseBody doesn't work for me. any suggestions ?

Answer (score -1):

Return something in the entity body... You can use `@ResponseBody`

```
public @ResponseBody MongoMarketDemand update(@RequestBody @Valid MongoMarketDemand marketDemand,     @PathVariable String id) {
   ...
   MongoMarketDemand updatedMarketDemand = ...
   return updatedMarketDemand;
}
```